# response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am using laravel 5.4.

While sending verification email, i got the aforementioned error.

I don't know what i am doing wrong this is my env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=shahzadshah5741@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=hussain57421
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: You should really change your GMail password now … (that you just appended an additional character to the password here is not that hard to figure out.)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Go to your Google Account Management page
   Under the Security options, click Edit link of Authorising applications & sites
2. Under gmail settings, you need to access https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and set 'Access for less secure apps' to "Enabled"